# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception., kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin

Tags: android, android-studio

I got the following errors and I have been searching for hours for an answer:

```
> Task :entities:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug

> Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin FAILED
e: Could not load module <Error module>

> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details
```

This error suddenly pops up. I tried the following things:

1. Removed the .idea dir
2. Restart my computer
3. Deleted all the gradle caches
4. Rebuild project

The error remains. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue when attempting to use either the kotlin-result or Arrow libraries. All I could find is [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-52757/Type-inference-for-builders-fails-if-inferred-from-a-function), but I have not been able to solve the problem myself.

Comment: The only way I could find the problematic import was by navigating through each class one by one until the infamous red line appears in some code.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR;** For those of you experiencing this after upgrading from AGP 7.x to AGP 8.x, I found reverting to AGP 7.x would provide more meaningful compile time errors.

I encountered the same issue after I upgraded Android Studio to Flamingo and AGP 8.0. I attempted to introduce a new library into my project for functional programming called kotlin-result and did some refactoring and then...

```
Task :[SOME OF MY MODULES]:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin FAILED
e: Could not load module <Error module>
```

After hours of reaching multiple dead ends I decided to apply the change on a branch from before the upgrade and then I got to see that there were a lot of concrete errors the compiler was simply swallowing.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, I had a function in which I was expecting a generic field to serialize to that type of class.

Android Studio recommended me to delete the generic that was passed to it because it picked it up implicitly (it was greyed out).

Without the specific class it failed.
With the class greyed out it works.

Answer (score -1):

Solution for me was to simply move `productFlavors` declarations after `buildTypes` declaration:

```
buildTypes {
    getByName("debug") {
        // ...
    }
    release {
        // ...
    }
}

flavorDimensions += "environment"

productFlavors {
    create("dev") {
        dimension = "environment"
        // ...
    }
    create("uat") {
        dimension = "environment"
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).